# Can't compare int and IQueryable<int> and need all rows, not FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am getting a type error.  Cannot compare int and IQueryable

I have looked for help on this, but have only seen info on .FirstOrDefault() and single and other methods to return on result row.  The issue I am having is that I want all rows where the product p matches the subcategory.  Normally it doesnt seem to be an issue when grabbing multiple rows, but while it seems to be common, I cant figure it out

```
var subcategoryId = someNumber;
productDetails =
from p in db.Products
where p.SubCategoryId == subCategoryId
select p;
```

Comment: are you sure the type of `someNumber` is `int`?

Comment: subCategoryId.Contains(p.SubCategoryId) ?

Comment: I would seem someNumber is in fact IQueryable<int>

Comment: The inappropriate use of `var` can hide so many mistakes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well, here I'd say the bigger mistake is naming an `IQueryable<int>` `someNumber`.  The variable name implies it is something it's not.

Comment: Agreed, but `int subcategoryId` would have given so much better errors.

Answer (score 1):

If `subCategoryId` is not a single value (seems like that) then try to use `Contains`

```
productDetails = from p in db.Products
                 where  subCategoryId.Contains(p.SubCategoryId)
                 select p;
```